# How to replace substring which may have spaces in between

Tags: string, lua, design-patterns, string-matching

In lua, I need to detect a substring which may contain spaces.

For instance,

I have a string

```
local str = "Hel lo World"
```

How do I replace "Hello" from this string?

Do I need to use patterns?

**EDIT**

I came up with something like this

```
local pattern = "[H][ ]*[e][ ]*[l][ ]*[l][ ]*[o]"
str:gsub(pattern,"text_to_replace")
```

Is that optimal?

Comment: Is this list of words like `Hello` predefined?

Comment: All the brackets `[]` in your code example are in fact useless, since there is only one character in each of them. `pattern = "H *e *l * l *o"` would work as well.

Comment: ah well! I was sort of generalizing it to detect other characters as well..
Something like
`[h][^a-z]*[e][^a-z]*[l][^a-z]*[l][^a-z]*[o]`
Hence the brackets! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a pattern generator like this:

```
local spaced_match = function(s)
    local pattern = ''
    for i=1,#s do
       pattern = pattern..s:sub(i,i)..' *'
    end
    return pattern
end

local h = 'hel lo world'
local newh = h:gsub(spaced_match('hello'),'text_to_replace')
```

Comment: yeah! that was what I had in mind. Just wanted to know if there was a better solution than the pattern which I had mentioned..

Answer (score 0):

create a mask of where letters/spaces are

Strip spaces

match/replace text

undo mask of letters/spaces

If you wanted to make a function that does it.

Comment: isn't using patterns easier?(as mentioned in the update to original question)

Comment: If all of your "hel lo" type words with spaces in it are predefiend, then yes. If not, I think finding the space locations/ strip them, replace and lastly, insert spaces and take in account the change of word length (from "hello" to "goodbye" if the word was changing length.

Comment: Edit: I can't think of a simple pattern that would apply for every case :(

Comment: How about this `[h][^a-z]*[e][^a-z]*[l][^a-z]*[l][^a-z]*[o]`?   can you think of any case where this pattern would fail?